# Is there a way to create an agent inside a delay/wait block?

Tags: anylogic

Is there a way to create an agent inside a delay/wait block? Basically at the start of the simulation I need to create a number of agents defined by a parameter in the middle of the model, and depending on the user's choices, the place where I need to insert these agents may change.

So what I would like to know, is there any way to simply create a certain number of agents within these delay/wait blocks, without having to place a source block before each station? (It's my last resource, but it would make the model very visually polluted).

I have found some function like:

```
delay.create();
```

or

```
delay.addAgentToContents(agent);
```

However, I don't know how to use, or even if it's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not directly. You have 2 options:

1. Use a warmup period to fill the system
2. Create a custom agent that you use instead of the Delay

For the 2nd option, your agent type would include a Enter/Exit blocks and a Delay in the middle. Also a paramter of type `int` named something like `numInitialAgents`.

In the flow of the agent, you have a Source that injects that many agents on start, which would immediately fill the Delay block.

Now replace all your normal Delay blocks with the custom agent type et voila.

PS: If you struggle with the Enter/Exit setup, see some advanced videos such as https://youtu.be/OWwjKqKUA1A?si=Ues0Hm6C1U5SlEFI